# Spring 3.2 Jackson 2.2 REST API

Tags: json, spring, api, rest

I am beginning with REST techniologies, and I choose Spring 3.2 and Jackson 2.2 . I have small question. I created REST API and it looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class WorkersController {

@Autowired
public DatabaseService dbService;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/workers", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ArrayList<Worker> getAllWorkersFromDatabase() {
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/workers/new", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes="application/json")
public String saveWorker(@RequestBody final WorkerDTO workerDto) {
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/workers/{workerid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public Worker getWOrkerByDatabaseId(@PathVariable Integer workerid) {
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/workers/{workerid}/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
public String editWorker(@PathVariable Integer workerid, @RequestBody Worker worker) {
}
}
```

When I make HTTP GET all is ok but I have problem with POST. When I am calling saveWorker() method I get:

```
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not  supported by the requested resource for the requested method
```

I imported required libraries:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I think the main problem is in configuration files and @RequestBody cant map JSON to DTO.   It is my Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.schedule.service")
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(DatabaseSpringConfig.class)
public class ServiceSpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{

@Override
protected void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    List<MediaType> jsonTypes = new ArrayList<>(jsonConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes());
    jsonTypes.add(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    jsonTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(jsonTypes);
    converters.add(jsonConverter);
}
```

}

My DTO:

```
public class WorkerDTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String name;
public String surname;

public WorkerDTO() {
}
}
```

Json:

```
{
"name": "asdssss",
"surname": "asdssssss"
}
```

And http call:

```
localhost:8080/Schedule-service/workers/new?Content-type=application/json
```

Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request

```
localhost:8080/Schedule-service/workers/new?Content-type=application/json
```

has a request parameter with name `Content-Type` and value `application/json`.

`HttpMessageConverter` classes, and `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in particular, don't look for request parameters, they look for headers.

You need to specify a `Content-Type` header for your request.